# Why Axios logs error 403 even when I catch it

Tags: javascript, express, axios

Based on axios docs, I have the catch block after my request, but even I catching the error and showing the Alert, on browsers console I got the message:

```
POST http://localhost:5000 403 (Forbidden)      spread.js:25
```

Why the message above ?
Is this the default browser behavior ?

Client:

```
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    alert(error);
  });
```

Server:

```
res.status(403).send('Error message');
```

Comment: [spread.js](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/b8f6f5049cf3da8126a184b6b270316402b5b374/lib/helpers/spread.js) is a "Syntactic sugar for invoking a function and expanding an array for arguments" module in the Axios source code.  The function being passed into it might be doing the console logging that you noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, at least Chrome by default logs every failed http request.